# Which box of fmp4 file contains CTTS information similar to that of ordinary MP4 file？

Tags: mp4, http-live-streaming, fmp4

I converted fmp4 files into TS files by imitating the code of converting MP4 files into TS files.
I encountered a problem:
There is CTTS box in MP4 file, but there is no CTTS box in fmp4 file. The information inside CTTS (PTS = STTS + CTTS) is needed when calculating video PTS. What should I do?
My h264 frame has no B frame. Do I need a CTTS box?

Comment: If you do not have B frames afaik you should be fine without a CTTS box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fmp4 encodes timestamps, flags and sizes in the trun box

Comment: Can you please explain how does edts/elts fit in (along with ctts and stts) when calculating PTS?